# How to style a control in Bootstrap to full height in mobile (with scrolling, fixed header/footer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When using my JQuery control (IOS-style list), in a Bootstrap Web Application, I need the control to take up the full screen height (minus header and footer) on any mobile sizes.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/46y43/1/

```
/*
  Live control Javascript not required for this example
  Note: I pasted my bootstrap CSS into the JSFiddle CSS panel,
  hence the large amount of styling. 
  (My styling is at the bottom).
*/
```

It should look something like the image below, but currently the height of the control is hard-wired so if you resize the control goes outside the window and the footer is lost:

[image]

The height needs to be 100% minus the headers, preferably complying with bootstrap. The only other answers I could find for fixed heights in Bootstrap did not adapt to the content area being larger than the screen height. This seems to be a deficiency in CSS, so suggestions/improvements welcomed (*I really miss Silverlight layouts!*).

The solution should avoid having any browser scrollbars if shown in a small browser window.

I added JQuery/Javascript tag in case the only solution is some form of dynamic resize, but a CSS only solution preferred (must support all major browsers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/46y43/2/

**CSS**:

```
.navbar-header{height:50px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  html {
      height:100%;
  }
    body{
        height:100%;
    }
    .container.body-content{
        height:100%;
        margin-top:-50px;
        padding-top:50px;
    }
     .container.body-content .row{
        height:100%;
    }
    .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2.col-sm-12{
    height:100%;
    }
    .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2.col-sm-12 .row{
    height:100%;
    }
    .ListView-Wrapper{
    height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
    }
}
```

**LESS**:

```
@navheight : '50px';


.navbar-header{height: @navheight ;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  html {
      height:100%;
  }
    body{
        height:100%;
    }
    .container.body-content{
        height:100%;
        margin-top: -@navheight;
        padding-top: @navheight;
    }
     .container.body-content .row{
        height:100%;
    }
    .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2.col-sm-12{
    height:100%;
    }
    .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2.col-sm-12 .row{
    height:100%;
    }
    .ListView-Wrapper{
    height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was very helpful. I added a separate `fullHeight` class rather than override all the Bootstrap columns and rows but that did the trick. Cheers! :)